# How to get visibility result of edit text on other activity?

Tags: android

I have a activity main and activity second.
Activity main has 3 text views and a button and Activity second has 3 edit texts a button and a save button, the third edit text is invisible, when I press the button the edit text becomes visible.

My problem is, how do I get the visibility state of that edit text?
I want to show the result when it is visible and make the textview visible
I also want it to be invisible when the button in second activity is not pressed

My current code in Activity main

```
// This method opens the second activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Open_Form);
    // Capture button clicks
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Start SecondActivity.class for result
            Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent3, ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE);
        }
    });
// This method is called when second activity finishes
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Check that it is the second activity with an OK result
if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get string data from Intent
            String Brand = data.getStringExtra("@id/etBrand");
            // Set text view with string
            TextView tvBrand = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvBrand);
            tvBrand.setText(Brand);
            tvBrand.getVisibility();{
                String Name = data.getStringExtra("@id/etName");
                TextView tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                tvName.setText(Name);
                tvName.getVisibility();{
                    String Size = data.getStringExtra("@id/etSize");
                    TextView tvSize = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSize);
                    tvSize.setText(Size);
                    tvSize.getVisibility();{
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my code for second activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_rod_dialog1);
EditText etSize = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSize);
    etSize.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Add_Size);
    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// Create the submit button
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSave);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Get the text from EditText and put the string to pass back into an Intent
            EditText etBrand = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBrand);
            String stringToPassBack = etBrand.getText().toString();
            Intent myIntent1 = getIntent();
            myIntent1.putExtra("@id/etBrand", stringToPassBack);
            // Get the text and put the string to pass back into an Intent
            EditText etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
            String stringToPassBack1 = etName.getText().toString();
            Intent myIntent2 = getIntent();
            myIntent2.putExtra("@id/etName", stringToPassBack1);
            // Get the text and put the string to pass back into an Intent
            EditText etSize = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSize);
            String stringToPassBack2 = etSize.getText().toString();
            Intent myIntent3 = getIntent();
            myIntent3.putExtra("@id/etSize", stringToPassBack2);

            // Close activity
            setResult(RESULT_OK_1, myIntent1);
            finish();
        }
    });
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Add_Size);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText etSize = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSize);
            etSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Add_Size);
            button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You check for RESULT_OK but you setResult for RESULT_OK_1.

Comment: That was a typing mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should but results as extra with putExtra() into your intent. Also you should use startActivity method this way.

Comment: Thank you, can you maybe please provide a example?

Comment: Formating in comments are afwul but I'll try. You should past in your second activity that instead of finish: Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class); intent.putExtra("Is EditText visible", etSize.getVisibility()); startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

To get the visibility of the edit text (and indeed any view) you can use [isShown()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29)

Comment: Thank you, can you maybe please provide a example?

Comment: It returns a Boolean of True if it is visible.  So if I understand your question correctly then you want to do a check in btn2's onClickListener to see if the field 'etSize' is visible.  In which case something along the lines of `if (etSize.isShown())` then do something

Comment: Oh, and looking at your code you are declaring multiple references to etSize in various places - you'll have a lot easier a time if you do it just once